# Cannot use Kineticjs in html5 

Tags: html, canvas, draggable, kineticjs

I want to use the Kinetic js library in order to make the drag and resize effect in my images on the canvas.
So I am following this example http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

My html let's say is like that:

```
.....
<div id="container"></div>
.....
```

Then on load I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    loadImage()
});

function loadImage(){

imageObj = new Image();      
imageObj.onload  = function(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 578, 200);
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();   

    var x = stage.width / 2 - 200 / 2;
    var y = stage.height / 2 - 137 / 2;

    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        x: x,
        y: y
    });

    image.draggable(true);

    // add cursor styling
    image.on("mouseover", function(){
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
    });
    image.on("mouseout", function(){
        document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    });
    layer.add(image);
    stage.add(layer);
};
imageObj.src = 'myImage.png';
}
```

But what I get is this message:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined"
referring I think in the container div. 
What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor call is not right.

Try

> ```
> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
>       container: 'container',
>       width: 578,
>       height: 363
> });
> ```

For the drag part, you can make your layer draggable with

> ```
> var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: true});
> ```

You can see a basic example of this working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/dVWxG/)

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. But is there also a way to get the canvas I already have in the html, instead of using the stage object?  so instead of doing canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); is there a way to use the same logic but using the stage ?

Comment: You might use the Kinetic [Shape](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/) for that

Comment: Ok I used canvas = layer.getCanvas(); ctx = layer.getContext(); and got what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setDraggable:

```
image.setDraggable(true);
```

But, have to ask, why dont you use the canvas constructor from Kinetic? I believe that you cannot use this library if you are manipulating the canvas directly

Comment: Ok, I tried with the canvas constructor. I add <div id="container"></div> in my html, and I edited my question so as to create the canvas too. What I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined" . Any ideas?